# Ejecutar archivo .py desde otro .py en Linux (ubuntu)

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

Vengo armando una proyecto de practica sin interfaz grafica y estoy dividiendo las secciones en diferentes .py. El tema es que me gustara hacer como un menú de opciones de las acciones que el usuario desee realizar pero no se como ejecutar otro .py dentro de un .py

Para que se entienda la idea:
Ej. un input donde lo que el usuario deba contestar es la accion a realizar con algun nro (ejemplo: agregar producto (1), eliminar producto (2) y asi sucesivamente). La idea es que a medida que selecciona la opcion se ejecuta ese .py correspondiente y luego regresa a ese menu principal.

Ejemplo de codigo:
db_connection.py

```
    import sqlite3

connection=sqlite3.connect("productos.db") #Creo la base de datos
cursor=connection.cursor() #Creo el cursor

try: #Intento crear la tabla que necesito, si existe omito la creacion
    cursor.execute(f"""CREATE TABLE stock(
    ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    NOMBRE VARCHAR(30),
    CANTIDAD INTEGER,
    PRECIO INTEGER
    )""")
    print("Conexion realizada")
except:
    print("Tabla ya creada")
    print("Conexion realizada")
```

eliminar_producto.py:

```
from db_connection import *
from funciones import product_search

delete=product_search()

cursor.execute(f"DELETE FROM stock WHERE ID={delete} ")#Se elimina el producto seleccionado por el usuario
connection.commit()
```

Como ven ahi, por una parte tengo la coneccion a la db y por otra parte la accion de eliminar X producto. La idea del menu.py (aun no creado) es que se pueda ejecutar desde este el "eliminar_producto.py"

Intente hacerlo importando os pero me decia que no tenia los permisos para ejecutar el archvio

Gracias

Comment: no sé que esperas como respuesta. Cual es el código de esos archivos?? Qué has intentado?? Podrías dar un [ejemplo mínimo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?. Por favor lee [ask] y vuelve a realizar el [tour] por si no quedo claro el funcionamiento del sitio

Comment: Gracias por la recomendacion. Ahji agregue dos .py de ejemplo donde creo que se puede entender mejor a lo que me refiero.
La idea es ejecutar por terminar el menu.py y que dependiendo la opcion que seleccione en ese menu me ejecute otro .py.

Ejemplo: opcion=int(input("Selecciona la opcion: (1) agregar producto, (2) eliminar producto"). Si el usuario selecciona la 2 se ejecuta eliminar_producto.py

Comment: y como sabe el script `eliminar_producto.py` que producto eliminar?? Lo que debes hacer es importar los scripts, no ejecutarlos por separado

Comment: eliminar_producto.py lo  sabe por la funcion que contiene la variable "delete" en el codigo que adjunte a la pregunta principal; Esa funcion la importe de otro .py que tiene funciones en comun para diferentes archivos.

A ver si entendi bien, me recomendas que lo que haga sea importar y ejecutar lo necesario y no ejecutar directo el archivo como tenia pensado?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La solucion mas siple que encontre fue la de meter todo el contenido del .py a ejecutar dentro de una funcion e importar dicha funcion para luego poder ejecutarla.

EL codigo del menu.py quedo de la siguiente forma:

```
from venta import init_venta
from agregar_producto import init_agregar
from eliminar_producto import init_eliminar

selection=int(input("""\n\nVENTAS Y STOCK\n\n¿Que accion desea realizar?:
1- Realizar venta
2- Cargar producto
3- Eliminar producto
4- Salir
----> """))

while selection!=4:
    if selection==1:
        init_venta()
    elif selection==2:
        init_agregar()
    elif selection==3:
        init_eliminar()
    else:
        print("Opcion incorrecta")
    selection=int(input("""\n\nVENTAS Y STOCK\n\n¿Que accion desea realizar?:
1- Realizar venta
2- Cargar producto
3- Eliminar producto
4- Salir
----> """))
```

Como pueden ver, las funciones que contienen todo el contenido de los diferentes .py se llaman init_XX. Al importar dichas funciones y utilizarlas en el while, logro que se corra el .py que necesito a la vez que realizada la accion que necesito vuelve al menu principal gracias al bucle

Comment: Aclaracion: Dicha solucion es la que encontre yo y la que mas optima me parecio luego de buscar diferentes soluciones. Esto no quiere decir que no haya una solucion mas eficiente para realizarlo